# Getting dictionary id dictionarys into resonable df

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, yahoo-finance

having trouble getting this dictionary of dictionaries into a resonable df.
want it to display all the tickers as columns and the attributes as an index.

```
          Columns: 'AZN.ST','ERIC-B.ST','SAND.ST'
Index:
accountsPayable.    value 1. value 2.   value 3
capitalSurplus      value 1. value 2.   value 3
cash                value 1. value 2.   value 3
etc...
```

```
import pandas as pd

tickers = ['AZN.ST','ERIC-B.ST','SAND.ST']

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(tickers)

state = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('quarterly','balance',reformat=True)
data = state['balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly']
newdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
newdf

#getting the latest reports
finaldf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newdf.iloc[0])
finaldf
```

[image: Code]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
finaldf = finaldf[0].apply(pd.Series)['2021-06-30'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
           intangibleAssets  ...  deferredLongTermLiab
AZN.ST         2.000600e+10  ...                   NaN
ERIC-B.ST      4.272000e+09  ...          3.798000e+09
SAND.ST        2.113600e+10  ...                   NaN

[3 rows x 29 columns]
```

**How it works:**

Consider a sample dataframe:

```
col_1 = {'val_1':1, 'val_2':3}
col_3 = {'val_1':4, 'val_2':5}
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col_1':[col_1, col_3]})
```

Input:

```
                      col_1
0  {'val_1': 1, 'val_2': 3}
1  {'val_1': 4, 'val_2': 5}
```

Now apply `pd.Series` to `col_1`

```
df = df['col_1'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
   val_1  val_2
0      1      3
1      4      5
```

Comment: TY for answer. I do get an error message when trying you code.

Comment: see picture i posted

Comment: Earlier you had this in your code `finaldf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newdf.iloc[0])` Now you are using this: `finaldf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newdf.iloc[0][0])`. That's why it gave the error. Try using `finaldf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newdf.iloc[0])` and then execute the solution I provided

Comment: Worked, TY so much!! so what exactly am i doing here: finaldf = finaldf[0].apply(pd.Series)['2021-06-30'].apply(pd.Series)

Comment: What is does is that it creates a new column for every key in the dictionary. check the edited answer